# Is it possible to create a Polymer element without Html?

Tags: html, dart, dart-polymer, polymer

My final objective is don't have to write HTML like this:

```
<div id='counter'>
     {{counter}}
  </div>

  <div>
     <button
        id="startButton"
        on-click="{{start}}">
        Start
     </button>
     <button
        id="stopButton"
        on-click="{{stop}}">
        Stop
     </button>
     <button
        id="resetButton"
        on-click="{{reset}}">
        Reset
     </button>
</div>
```

I would like to know if it is possible to create a Polymer-element without using HTML. For example I tried this:

```
@CustomTag('tute-stopwatch')
class TuteStopWatch extends PolymerElement {

ButtonElement startButton,
  stopButton,
  resetButton;

  @observable String counter = '00:00';

  TuteStopWatch.created() : super.created() {
    createShadowRoot()..children = [
      new DivElement()..text = '{{counter}}',

      new DivElement()..children = [
        startButton = new ButtonElement()..text = 'Start'
           ..onClick.listen(start),
        stopButton = new ButtonElement()..text = 'Stop'
           ..onClick.listen(stop),
        resetButton = new ButtonElement()..text = 'Reset'
           ..onClick.listen(reset)
      ]
    ];
  }
}
```

Previous code creates HTML and shadow root correctly, but it doesn't create the binding between the `@observable counter` and the text of the `DivElement`.

I know that this is caused because I am trying to create the shadow root after the element has been instantiated/created. So that I should create the template of the element in other place before the template has been bound with its observable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a manual data binding like this:

```
   changes.listen((changes) {
     for (var change in changes) {
        if (change.name == #counter) {
           myDivElement.text = change.newValue;
        }
     }
   });
```

[changes](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#observe/observe.Observable@id_changes) is a property of the [Observable](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#observe/observe.Observable) class, which [PolymerElement](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#polymer/polymer-polymer_element.PolymerElement) mixes in. (This is difficult to see in the API reference, as it currently doesn't show a class' mixins or the mixed in properties and methods.)

Polymer seems to be mostly about enabling declarative html based bindings. It may be worth exploring using custom elements and shadow dom directly, as you're not really using polymer for anything in this example. To do this you need to change the class definition to:

```
   class TuteStopWatch extends HtmlElement with Observable {
     ...
   }
```

And register your element with [document.register()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-dom-html.HtmlDocument@id_register). You also need to include the polymer.js polyfill for custom elements.

Comment: I guess `counterChanged(old) { xxx }` would work too, wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't know, is that a Polymer feature? I haven't been using Polymer. I've just been using custom elements, and the observable package, as this means I only need the small custom elements polyfill, rather than all of the shadow dom, and html imports stuff.

Comment: It's an observable feature. If an `@observable` or `@published` field `xxx` is modified `xxxChanged(oldVal)` is called.

Comment: Hmmm. Is there a source code transformer that adds these xxxChanged() methods to your class for you? Doesn't seem like a huge win to me, and adds another layer of complexity. I'd rather just keep it simple, and use changes.where((c) => c.name = #xxx).listen(...); But each to their own ;)

Comment: To make sure I'm not missing something - I tested this. It doesn't work. So there must be another step to enable these changed method calls - do you know what this is? I'm curious. https://gist.github.com/xxgreg/9863962

Comment: I only used this in normal Poylmer elements. Maybe I'm wrong and this is a Polymer feature. I would this find weird though. I'll add a note when I know more.

Comment: Looks like it must be in polymer. The transformer in package:observe, doesn't seem to do it either. https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/pkg/observe/lib/transformer.dart

Comment: You gist can't work because you don't inherit or implement Observable but I couldn't get xxxChanged work with Observable alone anyway. It seems to be a Polymer feature. I think your code is outdated. `ObservableMixin` should be `Observable`

Comment: Ahh. Copy and paste fail. Updated. But Still not called even when "extends Observable" is included. I don't understand where this xxxChanged() magic is implemented. Thanks fixed the ObservableMixin typo.

Comment: I found it in the polymer package file `declaration.dart` line 350 with a comment from jmesserly thinking about deprecation.