# Extending dart:html classes in dart

Tags: html, web, dart

I am new to Dart and I wonder if I can, for example, extend the DivElement class to create custom elements in one line of code. I am looking for something like this;

```
class RedBox extends DivElement {
    RedBox(text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.style.background = "red";
    }
}

RedBox myBox = new RedBox("Hello World");
document.body.append(myBox);
```

Of course I will have much more complex elements with custom functions. But just in general, is this possible?

When I try to run this, i get:

```
implicit call to super constructor 'DivElement()'
```

Comment: I think this is the nearest you can get

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677678

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can extend HTML elements, but there are a few requirements. The one you're running into now is that you need a `RedBox.created` constructor, and it can only redirect to its super class. `created` must be the only generative constructor, though you can add factory constructors.

Another requirement is that the element is registered with [document.registerElement](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.HtmlDocument#id_registerElement).

Try adding this:

```
class RedBox extends HtmlElement {
  RedBox.created() : super.created() {
    style.background = "red";
  }
  factory RedBox(text) => new Element.tag('my-redbox')..text = text;
}

document.registerElement('my-redbox', RedBox);
```

Comment: does it have to extend off HtmlElement? can it not extend DivElement as in the question?

Comment: You can extend DivElement, but you still need to have a `created()` constructor. Usually the only reason to extend an existing element is to take advantage of special parsing, in which case you need to write it as `<div is="my-redbox">`.

Answer (score 1):

Some note on extending HtmlElement.
Example:
https://api.dartlang.org/1.14.1/dart-html/HtmlDocument/registerElement.html
Pitfalls:

1. Extending non HtmlElement(e.g. PreElement) throws:

> HierarchyRequestError: Custom element XXX is a native PreElement
>   should be derived from HtmlElement or SvgElement.

2. Using extendsTag option with registerElement suppresses the above error but causes "new Element.tag('xxx')" to return an instance of HtmElement.

> document.registerElement('xxx', XXX, extendsTag:'pre');

Solution(Assuming extending PreElement):
Use 'document.registerElement('xxx', XXX, extendsTag:'pre');' and 'new Element.tag('pre','xxx');'

```
void main{
  document.registerElement('xxx',
      XXX,extendsTag: 'pre');
      querySelectior('body').append(new XXX()..text = 'hello');
  }
  class XXX extends PreElement{
    XXX.created():super.created(){}
    factory XXX(){
      return new Element.tag('pre','xxx');
    }
  }
```

Dart does not currently support library initialization. You must call document.registerElement in the main.

Tested with 1.14.0