# Extend svg.RectElement (factory constructor)

Tags: dart

I begin with Dart and I would like to extend RectElement class to create a MyRectElement class which is able to move rectangle in SVG area :

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:svg';

class MyRectElement extends RectElement{
  int xOrigin;
  int yOrigin;

  factory MyRectElement() {
  }
}

void main() {
  var rect = new MyRectElement();
  var container = querySelector("#container");
  container.append(rect);
}
```

But RectElement has a factory constructor.

I must admit that I don't understand factory constructor even if I read lots of posts about it...

What should I put in MyRectElement factory contructor ?

Comment: Looking at your goal, rather than your code, I think you're going about this wrong. You want to move about a Rect in an SVG.  Why not just create a generic RectElement and move it around as you please?  Why do you feel the need to subclass RectElement?  PS on the factory constructor front there should really be no need to use one in this subclass for your purposes.

Comment: I thought to subclass RectElement was more clean. But I followed your advice and it works. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Extending just the class is not supported.

You can build a Polymer element that extends a DOM element or if you don't want to use Polymer this question should provide some information [Is it possible to create a Polymer element without Html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677678)