# Breaking on exception: created called outside of custom element creation

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

```
Breaking on exception: created called outside of custom element creation.
```

i get this exception when i try to do the following, simply creating a class that extends HtmlElement

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelector('#list_view').children.add(new ListView.created());
}



class ListView extends HtmlElement{

  ListView.created() : super.created(){
    new Element.ul()..children = 
        [
         new Element.li()..text = 'test',
         new Element.li()..text = 'test'
         ];
  }

}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shouldn't do this inside the constructor of a Polymer element

```dart
new Element.ul()..children = 
        [
         new Element.li()..text = 'test',
         new Element.li()..text = 'test'
         ];
```

move it to `ready()`, `attached()` or some other method.

Comment: but i am not using polymer at all, and created is the only constructor i can find in HtmlElement

Comment: Sorry, didn't look close enough. You just can't extend these elements this way. You can create a custom element without Polymer but I don't know how. This is still a Polymer element but without the HTML markup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677678

Comment: i don't see why not, i also tried document.registerElement('list-view',ListView); but it doesnt seem to have any effect, what you mentioned is exactly what i am trying to do but without polymer, just using pure html5 standards, shadowdom and custom elements

Comment: You should believe it even when you don't see it ;-) I'm sure there are some question/answers about this already but couldn't find one.
Even if it is possible to create custom elements without Polymer, if you want to do this, just use Polymer because here you'll find plenty of documentation.

Comment: i am just playing around i am the only users of my apps ;)

Comment: i think its because the features are experimental http://www.chromium.org/blink/web-components and you should enable the flags first thats why the registerElment wasnt working

Comment: `registerElement` is used by Polymer regularily since months. But you have to prepare the element somehow before registering it. A correctly set-up Polymer element can be registered with `registerElement` without enabling any experimental settings.

Comment: but registerElement is not related to polymer , in html5 you also need to call it to register your custom elements i think its a part of dart:html package

Comment: As I already mentioned above, you **can** create custom elements without Polymer but I don't know about docs. I suggest to just go with Polymer because its well documented and used widely.